# Is it possible to prove the completeness of $\ell^2$-space without using Minkowski inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, alternative-proof

The "standard" proof of completeness of $\ell^2-$space uses Minkowski inequality. More specifically, the proof presented in *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications with Applications* by Kreyszig starts by considering a Cauchy sequence of $\ell^2$ sequences. Then it shows that, the sequences are actually Cauchy "slot-wise". From there, we could construct a new sequence. It then shows that the sequence is in $\ell^2$ as well by using Minkowski inequality.

I am wondering if there is any proof that does not use Minkowski inequality. Thank you.

Comment: The Minkowski inequality is just the triangle inequality for the metric induced by the $\ell^2$ norm. It's usually dubious to try and prove an estimate in a metric space without the triangle inequality since it is the only thing used in estimations, so I would doubt the answer is affirmative.

Comment: Probably not. The notion of complete space is intrinsic to the notion of convergence, and this is related to the metric and is triangular inequalities (Minkowski inequalities in $ l^2$).

Comment: @AdamHughes The reason I'm asking is, the other day I heard someone talking about a proof using "tail argument" but I've never heard of that

Comment: @Misakov tails is a term used in sequence spaces like $\ell^2$ where you estimate the main term of a sum separately from the convergent tail which can be made arbitrarily small, but that in fact regularly expresses your sequence as a head sum plus a tail sum which you then estimate separately and join to the main argument using the triangle inequality. So that technique doesn't avoid minkowski, in fact it **relies** on it.

Comment: @AdamHughes If you don't mind, would you write down that proof for me please? Thank you. It's always interesting to see "different" proofs.

Comment: @Misakov I'm sorry, but that's not possible:  it's not a proof because it's not a result, it's just a technique used in estimates.